# For Xamarin.Forms application what is the difference between Async and my using await Task.Run(() => to run a backend database update?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms so this question is in particular for when I am using that application as maybe it's different than normal C# apps.

When a button is pressed I am using a TapGestureRecognizer to call an OnTapped method.  This then updates button colors on my page and at the same time the database is updated.

To perform this asynchronously I would like to use:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
```

Here's the actual code:

```
async void OnTapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as ButtonTemplate;
    if (Counts.phaseTableSelectedCardCount != 0)
    {
        var canContinue = await this.DisplayAlert("Selector", "Changing this will remove all previously selected cards from the deck", "OK", "Cancel");
        if (canContinue == false)
            return;
     }
     var settingId = SetButtons(btn.Text);
     await Task.Run(() => AddDetailSection(settingId));
 }
    
 public void AddDetailSection(int settingId)
 {
     vm.IsBusy = true;
     App.DB.UpdateData();
     vm.IsBusy = false;
 }
```

Are there any likely Xamarin / threading issues with my doing it this way or is there a better way where I mark AddDetailSection as an Async method and if so how could I do it better?

Comment: Does your `App.DB` expose async version of `UpdateData`?

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to use `TaskCompletionSource`
.

Remove await from `Task.Run` and use it when you are waiting `tcs.Task`

It is better to creat async version of method `AddDetailSection`